# How to get a different name for a doxygen man page for a utility program

Tags: c, doxygen, manpage

I have a C program called `ncdump.c`, and I am documenting it with doxygen.

When I generate the man page, I get one called `ncdump.c.3`. This is not helpful. I need `ncdump.1`.

I know how to change the man page section in the Doxyfile, but how do I get rid of the ".c"?

Answer (score 2):

Set MAN_EXTENSION to .1 and use a @page ncdump to document your program, e.g.

```
/** @page ncdump ncdump tool 
 *
 *  @section usage Usage Information
 *  Information on how to use this application.
 */
```